# Does the uniqueIdentifier stays the same if an user resets his apple device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uniqueidentifier, uidevice

If i restore or reset an iphone/ipod/ipad, does the uniqueIdentifier  stays the same or does it change?

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stays the same. The unique identifier (also known as UDID) identifies the hardware, not the software.

Comment: Thank you ver much for your fast reply.